# Have dialog link go to html login page if javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a site which has javascript in it.

In my site if a user **clicks** on login or register button a modal popup will be shown.

What I need to know is if the user has disable javascript in his/her browser they should be sent to a normal html signup page (Like in imdb.com) when the user clicks the login link.

Give me some tips on what I should do to get result like that.

I am a newbie so don't be too harsh in your reply.

Comment: please search the site for similar questions first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355359/redirect-to-another-page-if-javascript-is-disabled

Comment: Neither of those "duplicate" questions are duplicates of this question. They are asking about redirecting (if JS is disabled) *when the page is loaded* not when a link is clicked.

Comment: I did search for my question but didn't find one like mine. Thats why i asked for it. My apologies if my question is wrong. But pls try to understand what i ask.

Comment: I re-wrote the question to make it clearer that you want to redirect on click. Next time please make such distinction much clearer, especially since you found examples that did NOT answer your question. Anyway you got your answer

Comment: @mplungjan - Should probably have removed the term "redirect", since that was what threw me. "navigate" would have been less confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you set dynamic `onclick` handler for your button and prevent the default event (in the example below with `return false`). If JavaScript is disabled, the original event (redirection) will work.

*HTML:*

```
<a href="/path/to/normal/sign/up.html" id="login">
```

*JavaScript:*

```
document.getElementById("login").onclick = function() {
    // show popup
    return false;
};
```

Comment: I tried this many times but is not working for me. Can u tell me where i made wrong. Here is my code:

Comment: document.getElementById("goo").onclick = function jstest() {
 alert("Success")
    // show popup
 return false;
};

Comment: its working on jsfiddle.net but not when i am working with it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a normal link to the sign up page
2. Add [an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) to create the modal
3. Prevent [the default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) of clicking on the link