# How to redirect if JavaScript and meta redirect are disabled?

Tags: html, redirect, noscript

How to redirect if JavaScript and `<meta redirect>` are both disabled? Is there any way to redirect a page if both are disabled?

I found the useful questions [How to redirect if javaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489376/how-to-redirect-if-javascript-is-disabled) and [redirect to another page if javascript is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355359/redirect-to-another-page-if-javascript-is-disabled) which are redirecting using `<meta redirect>`, but if I disable meta redirect from e.g. the Firefox [Web Developer extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) then it will not redirect. Below is the image which shows how to disable JavaScript and meta redirects.

[image]

One more solution we have is that we can hide the `html` or `body` elements but anyone can use Firebug or other tool to make it visible, and which is not a trick now.

Do we have any option to work with `<noscript>` in this case or any server-side script (like PHP) to make it work?

Comment: You cannot "find" from php (server side) if javascript (client side) is disabled.

Comment: Agreed but, there is no solution for that?

Comment: Without Php, without javascript, without Meta Tags... you cannot redirect.

Comment: Read this article, it have a few more ways.http://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden field.

```
<asp:Hidden runat="server" ID="JSCheck" />
```

Then on page load, add the following script.

```
string sJSCheckValue = "1";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "jscheck", "document.getElementById(\"" + JSCheck.ClientID + "\").value = "+ sJSCheckValue +";", true);
}
```

on button press check if the value exists.

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bool IsJavaScriptEnabled = JSCheck.value == sJSCheckValue;
//Redirect Here
}
```